# Sequential update statements

Tags: sql, t-sql

When using multiple SETs on a single update query like

```
update table set col1=value1,col2=col1
```

is there an order of execution that will decide the outcome, when the same column is left or right of an equals sign? As far as I've tested so far, it seems when a column is used to the right of an equals as a data source, then its value is used from BEFORE it gets a new value within the same update statement, by being to the left of an equals sign elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that SQL Server always uses the old values when performing an `UPDATE`.  This would best be explained by showing some sample data for your table:

```
col1 | col2
1    | 3
2    | 8
3    | 10

update table set col1=value1,col2=col1
```

At the end of this `UPDATE`, the table should look like this:

```
col1   | col2
value1 | 1
value1 | 2
value1 | 3
```

This behavior for `UPDATE` is part of the ANSI-92 SQL standard, as this SO question discusses:

**[SQL UPDATE read column values before setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760479/sql-update-read-column-values-before-setting)**

Here is another link which discusses this problem with an example:

http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server/Using_Old_Values_to_Define_New_Values_in_UPDATE_Statements.html

You can assume that in general SQL Server puts some sort of lock on the table during an `UPDATE`, and uses a snapshot of the old values throughout the entire `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: My tests confirm this, but I would like it even more if there was some documentation to back this up.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I didn't find anything specifically for SQL Server, _but_ this behavior for `UPDATE` is part of the ANSI-92 SQL standard, to which SQL Server highly likely closely adheres.